# Is a hashed shard key right for me?

Tags: mongodb

Assume my documents look something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53d9560f2521e7a28f550a78"),
  "tenantId" : "tenant1",
  "body" : "Some text - it's the point of the document."
}
```

There are a couple of obviously bad shard key choices:

`{tenantId : 1}` This would eventually give me large, unsplittable chunks.

`{_id : 1}` There are a lot of writes and no updates. The ascending key would give me hotspots.

I think I'm left with two possibilities:

`{tenantId : 1, _id : 1}` The hotspot problem with _id is mitigated by the addition of tenantId. I can easily search with this full key.

`{_id : "hashed"}` No hotspots, but I have concerns....

My concern with the hashed key is that it's now random. In [Scaling MongoDB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449303218), the author warns against random keys because:

> The configuration server notices that Shard 2 has 10 more chunks than
>   Shard 1 and decides it should even things out. MongoDB now has to load
>   a random five chunks’ worth of data into memory and send it to Shard
>   1. This is data that wouldn’t have been in memory ordinarily, because it’s a completely random order of data. So, now MongoDB is going to be
>   putting a lot more pressure on RAM and there’s going to be a lot of
>   disk IO going on (which is always slow).

So, my question is: Are hashed keys only a good choice if your only other choice is a monotonically ascending key? In my case, would the combination of tenantId and _id be better?

**Update:** To answer a question in the comments, we only ever retrieve these documents one-by-one. So depending on which shard key we choose, queries would be like these:

```
{_id : "53d9560f2521e7a28f550a78"}
```

or

```
{_id : "53d9560f2521e7a28f550a78", tenantId : "tenant1"}
```

Comment: The hash key should depend on how your search-queries look. They should be the field you search for most frequently so the mongos can forward the query to the right shard.

Comment: I believe that shard key should depend entirely on what your queries are. But if your concern is hotspots then you can simply go for `{ _id : 1}` and all your data would be divided to all the shards. This will (on an average) cause all the queries to go to every shard and you will have a balanced (may or may not the fastest) query execution.

Comment: But `{ _id : 1}` *would* give me hotspots, no? It's an ascending key.

Comment: I agree with your evaluation of `_id` and `tenantId` as inappropriate shard keys, and `{_id : 1}` will direct all inserts to one shard as a monotonic key. But, to help you pick the shard key from the other choices, I'd like to know what "typical" queries look like.

Comment: I updated my question with how we query.

Comment: If you just pull out one at a time by `_id`, hashed `_id` should work very well, directing queries to only one shard per read but evenly distributing writes.

Comment: Thanks. So is a hashed key somehow better than the kind of random keys described in Scaling MongoDB? This is the bit I'm not quite grasping.